# setOnClickListener not works in Canvas and FrameLayout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

I am making a qr code scanning screen. There is a camera view in the background and scanning animation on it. At the bottom there are two image views that I added programmatically. These image views are drawn on a FrameLayout. Neither image view nor layout is clicked. I added button, image button instead of ImageView but setOnClickListener did not work.

I tried:

- I gave id to image views (values/ids.xml) and it did not work.
- Image view bringToFront() did not work
- I made the layout clickable and focusable but it didn't work again

Draw method

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        if (!isUserPremium) {
            prepareAlertText(canvas);
        }

        drawKeyboardBtn(canvas);
        drawFlashButton(canvas);
        drawRectangleAndLine(canvas, paint);
    }
```

drawKeyboardBtn function

```
private void drawKeyboardBtn(Canvas canvas) {
        int leftPadding = (int) (getWidth() * 0.23);
        int topPadding = (int) (getHeight() * 0.85);
        int layoutWidth = (int) (getHeight() * 0.1);
        int layoutHeight = (int) (getHeight() * 0.1);


        ImageView keyboardImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(layoutWidth, layoutHeight);

        layoutParams.setMargins(leftPadding, topPadding, 0, 0);
        keyboardImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        keyboardImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard);
        keyboardImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        keyboardImageView.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        frameLayout.addView(keyboardImageView);

        keyboardImageView.setClickable(true);
        keyboardImageView.setFocusable(true);
        keyboardImageView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


        //Also not worked
        //frameLayout.setClickable(true);
        //frameLayout.setFocusable(true);
        //frameLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        //Also not worked
        // frameLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //    Log.e("GraphicOverlay", "onClick: " + v.getId());
        //    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Keyboard clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // });

        keyboardImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.e("GraphicOverlay", "onClick: " + v.getId());
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Keyboard clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });

        frameLayout.measure(getWidth(), getHeight());
        frameLayout.layout(leftPadding, topPadding, leftPadding, topPadding);

        frameLayout.draw(canvas);
    }
```

[UI View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODOoo.jpg)

[Full Code Github Repo](https://github.com/eminyazan/flutter_barcode_scanner/tree/master/android/src/main)

Answer (score 0):

`onDraw(..)` is called whenever UI is rendered / displaying / created. And these `keyboardImageView` and `frameLayout` are generated when entering `onDraw(..)` and cleaned when leaving `onDraw()` (because these are local variables).

How about redesigning your UI hierarchy like below?
Basically, we shouldn't create AndroidViews nor anything such as `Paint()` inside `onDraw(..)`.

```xml
<FrameLayout ... >
  <CameraView .. />
  
  <KeyboardView .. 
     onClick="onclickKeyboardButton" />

  <Button .. 
     onClick="onClick..." />

</FrameLayout>
```